# EACCES on NewRelic on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, newrelic

I'm using NewRelic on and I keep getting this exception:

```
Error: listen EACCES
 at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
 at Server._listen2 (net.js:1024:19)
 at Server._listen2 (/srv/node/pse/releases/20150130185610/node_modules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:71:23)
 at listen (net.js:1065:10)
 at net.js:1147:9
 at /srv/node/pse/releases/20150130185610/node_modules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
 at dns.js:72:18
 at /srv/node/pse/releases/20150130185610/node_modules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
 at /srv/node/pse/releases/20150130185610/node_modules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
 at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:486:13)
 at process.<anonymous> (/srv/node/pse/releases/20150130185610/node_modules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:18:15)
 at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
 at startup (node.js:119:16)
 at node.js:929:3
```

I have no idea what's going on here. Does anyone have a clue?
This only happens on a EC2 instance, I can't reproduce it on localhost.

Thanks!